# Instant messaging vs Messaging service?

Tags: soa, openfire, middleware, instant-messaging

I am reading a bit about the message oriented middleware for SOA. The question which is not clear to me is difference between Instant messaging and Messaging service. Could someone help me to understand this ?

Comment: Message Oriented middleware for SOA are basically the XML and the JSON that are language agnostic. where in your SOAP/REST server can be in python and client can be in java; both talk using message oriented middleware like JSON/XML.


However, the instant messaging feature is completely different; its purpose is to enable subscription based communications with buddies to talk with each other (openfire/ejabbered). In this process one can use middleware services too.

Comment: If you want to do instant messaging look at eJabberD open source project. Instant messaging across a service bus is just going to add too much overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instant messaging is communication between humans using text messages.

Messaging service is event communication between machines using messages. Those messages are typically packed with information about an event that needs to be processed somehow. There are some pattern commonly implemented by messaging services.

- Publish/Subscribe - A publisher sends events to multiple subscribers that can decide what events they want to subscribe to.
- Message queue - Messages are sent to a queue used to hold events in a buffer. The messages awaits a consumer to consume messages and process the events. This implements a decoupling in time between systems as well as workload balancing.

Message events typically hold data in some machine readable format, such as XML, JSON, EDIFACT etc.

Another way to look at it: Messaging services can be used to build instant messaging software. The XMPP protocol is an example of that.

Comment: Ok .. thanks for the detailed response.I have one more query. Lets say i need a live/Instant update from the client at the server. Will the messaging service be slow compared to the instant messaging in this case ?

Comment: As I said - messaging services are used (sometimes) to implement instant messaging. Like IRC. No, there is nothing restricting messaging to be slow.

Comment: Simply put, IM is a use case for a messaging service.